# understanding list[i-1] vs list[i]-1

Tags: java, arrays, list, variables

Hopefully this is a simple answer that I am just failing to understand. Full code is

```
public static void mystery(int[] list) {
       for( int i = list.length - 1; i>1; i --) {
           if (list[i] > list[i - 1]) {
               list[i -1] = list[i] - 2;
               list[i]++;
            }
    }
}
}

and lets say we are using a list of [2,3,4].
```

I know that it will output 2,2,5 but I am unclear how to actually work through it. I understand that the list.length is 3 here, and I understand that the for loop will only run once, but I am very unclear what happens at the list[i - 1] = list[i] - 2; area. Should it be list[2-1] = list[2] - 2? How does the two being outside the bracket effect it differently?

Much thanks.

Comment: `list[i - 1]` gets (or, as in this example, sets) the element 1 before i.  `list[1] - 1` gets the element at i and subtracts 1. Pretty much how it reads.

Comment: list[i -1] = list[i] - 2;  is not an equality. It transfers list[i] - 2 to list[i -1].

Answer (score 0):

Well the code is quite simple:

```
if (list[i] > list[i - 1])
```

The above line compares current element in the list (to be honest, it's an array, not a list, but lets stick with your naming convention) with its previous element. Considering your sample input, it compares `4>3` If it is greater than the previous element (and it is), it subtracts 2 from the previous element and adds 1 to current element.

```
list[i -1] = list[i] - 2; // list[2-1]=4-2     ->  list[1]=2
list[i]++;  //list[2]=list[2]+1                ->  list[2]= 4+1 = 5
```

After the first iteration you can say that the last number is 5 and the last-but-one number is 2. The next iteration checks the condition `2>2`. It is false, nothing changes, hence the result array [2,2,5].

Note that the loop goes from the end of the list to the beginning!

Comment: Thank you everyone, with your tips and some patience I just broke through the proverbial "barrier". I feel rather silly now.